# How to get actual stock prices with yfinance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf

stock = yf.Ticker("ABEV3.SA")

data1= stock.info


print(data1)
```

There is "bid" and "ask", but no actual stock price.

Comment: There is another way to get the stock price, you can use requests to get a response from a free stock api, i could give few example lines its very simple.

Comment: Unless you specifically care about the last price the stock actually traded at, people usually just use the average of bid and ask for this.

Answer (score 28):

I used this filtering combination to get only the last quote.

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['ABEV3.SA']
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_yahoo = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    data = ticker_yahoo.history()
    last_quote = data['Close'].iloc[-1]
    print(ticker, last_quote)
```

Comment: Does not works anymore !! json.decoderError !!?

Comment: Still working here, @PremKumarTiwari.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
import yfinance as yf

stock = yf.Ticker("ABEV3.SA")
price = stock.info['regularMarketPrice']
print(price)
```

Comment: Note that `currentPrice` is also available which returns the same value as of version `0.1.74`

Comment: Weirdly, sometimes it's one or the other so I'll use `stock.info.get('regularMarketPrice', stock.info.get('currentPrice'))`

Answer (score 11):

This method returns the most updated value in my testing.

```
def get_current_price(symbol):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    todays_data = ticker.history(period='1d')
    return todays_data['Close'][0]

print(get_current_price('TSLA'))
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the last closing price use this:

```
import yfinance as yf

tickerSymbol = 'AMD'

tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)
todayData = tickerData.history(period='1d')
todayData['Close'][0] #use print() in case you're testing outside a interactive session
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
data = yf.Ticker("ABEV3.SA")
data = data.history(start="2010-01-01",  end=now)
print(data)
```

Comment: your last line is incorrect.  should probably be `print(df)`

Answer (score 2):

this is what looks like realtime quote to me:

```
import yfinance as yf
yca = yf.Ticker("YCA.L").history(interval="1m", period = "1d")
yca['Close'][-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few years late but for people looking for a solution to this question.

```
import yfinance as yf

def current_price(instrument):
    data = yf.Ticker(instrument).history(period="1d", interval="1m")
    return data["Close"].iloc[-1]

print(current_price("TSLA"))
```

This example gets the data in minute intervals and returns the latest "Close" data.

Comment: I should have added that this method will get the data in 1 minute intervals and the last 'Close' data will be from the last minute interval.

Answer (score 1):

The bid and ask prices are actually what are quoted on the exchange. A bid price is what a market maker is prepared to pay to buy shares, an ask is the price market makers require before selling. The spread is the difference between bid and ask.

What is usually referred to as the stock price is an average of the bid and ask prices. How the average is calculated depends on the exchange. If your feed does not offer a mid price provided by the exchange, then for many purposes it is sufficient to take the mean of the bid and ask.

Opening and closing prices are also determined by the exchange and may not be the first or last trades, but an average of the first or last 15 minutes trading, or may include after-hours prices.

Some details of how the LSE specifies ticker data:
[LSE ticker data](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/help/whats-issuer-profile-overview?lang=en#what-is-ticker-)

And, if you want to get into the nitty-gritty, a bit more detail on how orders are matched and generate price data:

[Idiots Guide to the London Stock Exchange's SETSmm](https://www.proactiveinvestors.co.uk/companies/news/81/idiots-guide-to-the-london-stock-exchanges-setsmm-0379.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get current price for multiples stocks:

```
stocks = ['PETR4.SA', 'ELET3.SA', 'VALE3.SA']

df = yf.download(' '.join(stocks), period='1d', progress=False)
df = df['Close']

for stock in stocks:
    if stock not in df or len(df[stock]) == 0: # this verification is important if trading session is closed
        continue
    quote = df[stock][0]
    print('%s = %.2f'%(stock, quote))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is using yfinance Ticker's fast_info where you can get both the actual price and the closing price of the previous trading day:

```
import yfinance as yf

tckr = yf.Ticker( "TSLA" )
info = tckr.fast_info
actual_price = info.last_price
previous_price = info.previous_close

print( actual_price, previous_price )
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

yfinance has download function which let's you download the stock price data for a specified period. for e.g. I'll use the same stock that you wanted data for.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("ABEV3.SA", start="2020-03-01", end="2020-03-30")
```

above line downloads data for march month as the specified date is that.

the data will be a pandas dataframe so you can directly use that for operation.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it seems that this only returns historical data at least when I try this `d = yf.download('DHER.DE', start='2020-03-01', end='2020-12-09')` it return only the data until yesterday. Is there any way to access the current bid?

Comment: For getting the current price in yahoo, you can take a look at this repository: [excel_stock_webscrape](https://github.com/rodionlim/excel_stock_webscrape)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will get current price for list of symbols and add all result in dict.

```
import yfinance as yf

symbols = ["TSLA", "NIO"]
result = {}
for symbol in symbols:
    data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    today_data = data.history(period='1d')
    result[symbol] = round((today_data['Close'][0]),2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].