# Python : Getting current Bitcoin price from Yahoo finance with yfinance module

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm trying to read and display the current Bitcoin market price in Python, using the yfinance module/library. 
It works fine for currency pairs or market indices but BTC-USD doesn't seem to have any returned data which contains the current price.
For other indices there's a bid/ask price and I just take the average but I guess BTC has no spread...but I can't figure out which field has the 'current market price'
   Suggestions please.

Thanks,

This code works but it's showing the opening price, not the current market price:

```
BTC = yF.Ticker("BTC-GBP")
print("Bitcoin Current : ", round(BTC.info['open'],0))
print("        Day     : ", round(BTC.info['dayLow'], 0), "-", round(BTC.info['dayHigh'], 0))
print("        52 Week : ", round(BTC.info['fiftyTwoWeekLow'], 0), "-", round(BTC.info['fiftyTwoWeekHigh'], 0))
```

Comment: You can try the suggestions on this question [How to get actual stock prices with yfinance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104362/how-to-get-actual-stock-prices-with-yfinance)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Yahoo change their API regularly. I found a solution. I have to use `fast_info` instead of `info` and then there's a key called `'lastPrice'`:

```
CurrentPrice = Commod.fast_info['lastPrice']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try/check `regularMarketPrice`?

```
print("Bitcoin Current : ", round(BTC.info['regularMarketPrice'], 0))
```

Comment: Thanks.  That key doesn't seem to exist.  I printed off all keys and the only ones with prices are: 
'previousClose': 33715.82, 
'open': 33715.82, 
'dayLow': 32665.2, 
'dayHigh': 33810.54, 
'regularMarketPreviousClose': 33715.82, 
'regularMarketOpen': 33715.82, 
'regularMarketDayLow': 32665.2, 
'regularMarketDayHigh': 33810.54, 
'fiftyTwoWeekLow': 16391.438, 
'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': 38497.27, 
'fiftyDayAverage': 33825.117, 
'twoHundredDayAverage': 26447.53,